# Identification of Android app

Tags: php, android

I have website to which there is a possibility that user may login from several Android app for example 5  Android apps. These apps are partly native ( login functionality)and partly  webview ( business functionality)
I want to develop Php page so that it will identify from which Android app user is logged in and show only specific data based on app loggedin.

For example I have jewellery, automobile, garment business under one website. I want to that if user logged in from jewellery app he should see only jewellery related product. If user logged In from automobile app he should see only automobile related product s.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I identify with which Android app user loggedin in Php page.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's simple, you can send a unique string from each application and check from server the response and send back relative results.

Comment: Okay thanks I am not developer but wanted to know how this functionality can be implemented  at my website thanks.

Comment: You also might be able to just login via WebView and the app develeoper sends out to the app a user specific identifier received from the WebView as well. Just Google search it.